# w3c validator HTML5 xmlns

Tags: html, validation, w3c-validation

I couldn't get my website to validate in W3C markup validation.

Here is an example of one of the validation errors.

`Error: Attribute xmlns:content not allowed here.`

I have done some research and some articles recommend us to change the:
`xmlns:name="http://url" syntax into the prefix="name:http://url"`

However I am having multiple xmlns attribute.
Not sure how to write the prefix in this case.

Original:

```
`<html lang="en" dir="ltr"
  xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
  xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"
  xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
  xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
  xmlns:sioc="http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#"
  xmlns:sioct="http://rdfs.org/sioc/types#"
  xmlns:skos="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#">`
```

Is it separate by a space between each attribute?

`<html lang="en" dir="ltr" prefix="content:http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/ dc:http://purl.org/dc/terms/ foaf:http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/">`

or we should separate by `\n` new line?
I have checked in w3.org website and it looks like they separate the attribute in new line.
Am I right?
http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-rdfa-core-20111215/

Comment: Are you writing HTML5... or XHTML5+RDF? Because that's a whole lot of stuff that shouldn't be in an HTML5 document.

Comment: Not very sure, in fact the code is come together with my drupal theme.

Comment: I believe it should be HTML5+RDF.

Comment: It looks this is related to html.tpl.php in zen template in Drupal.

Comment: Updating to latest version of zen theme seem to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use elements from arbitrary namespaces in HTML 5. For that you need to be using XML, and for validation you need a suitable DTD or Schema that includes all the namespaces you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

You need a XHTML doctype to go before your html tag. You can use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

And there must be `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` also on the `html` tag. So this passes the W3C **XHTML** validation at https://validator.w3.org/ :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en" dir="ltr"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
  xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"
  xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
  xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
  xmlns:sioc="http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#"
  xmlns:sioct="http://rdfs.org/sioc/types#"
  xmlns:skos="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#">
<head><title></title></head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry but I have a `<!DOCTYPE html>` on top. I think the problem is not caused by doctype. It looks like w3c validator not allowed attribute such as "xmlns:content".

Comment: That Doctype references a DTD that doesn't include *any* of the namespaces mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The Web page contains RDFa markup, which is allowed in HTML 5. The [HTML+RDFa 1.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/REC-html-rdfa-20150317/) has [a section specifically dedicated to the `@xmlns:` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/REC-html-rdfa-20150317/#xmlns--prefixed-attributes).

It says that the use of `@xmlns:` is deprecated in RDFa 1.1 but still allowed for backward compatibility. So, if possible, it should not be used. Then, the following section on [Conformance Criteria for @xmlns:-Prefixed Attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/REC-html-rdfa-20150317/#conformance-criteria-for-xmlns--prefixed-attributes) indicates that:

> For documents conforming to this specification, attributes with names that have a case insensitive prefix matching "`@xmlns:`" MUST be considered conforming. Conformance checkers SHOULD accept attribute names that have a case insensitive prefix matching "`@xmlns:`" as conforming. Conformance checkers SHOULD generate warnings noting that the use of `@xmlns:` is deprecated. Conformance checkers MAY report the use of `xmlns:` as an error.

I understand that the W3C HTML validator is adopting the stricter conformance check where `xmlns:` is reported as an error, although I find it strange because it SHOULD rather generate a warning.